# Error: Cannot find .net assembly during FxCop analysis

Tags: msbuild, fxcop

I'm running FxCop from MSBuild and during the analysis it throws an error stating that it could not find the System.XML assembly and that I need to specify the location using the /directory parameter, which I then did but it didn't work. Any idea what I should do? I am running it on projects built on .Net 4.0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically the Gac has [changed in 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why)

First use FxCop 10.0, not FxCop 1.36.
    .Net 4.0 has a [private Gac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why)

Set FxCop to search the Gac
If you're using an FxCop project (*.FxCop)
    open the FxCop project with FxCop (Gui)
    Project -> Options -> Spelling & Analysis
    Checkmark "Search the Global Assembly Cache for missing references"
    ok, save.

If you're using MSBuild.Community.Tasks
    in your FxCop "SearchGac="true"