# Where is the .NET Framework Global Assembly Cache?

Tags: .net-4.0, gac

I installed the VS2010 and .NET 4.0, then I compiled an assembly and ran the gacutil using the exe available on

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools
```

The output of the executable said the assembly was sucessfully installed on Global Assembly Cache. However, when I go to `%WINDIR%\assembly` folder I cannot find the assembly I installed using the .NET Framework 4.0 `gacutil`.

I've seen some posts saying the .NET Framework 4.0 has a separated GAC, but what I haven't found was where it is located.

May someone to help me to check where can I see the Global Assembly Cache of .NET Framework, as it used to work on previous version (`%WINDIR%\assembly`)?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Yes, there are two distinct GACs as from .NET 4.0

See here: [.NET 4.0 has a new GAC, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why)

As stated below, the new physical location is %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\ (you can interogate it using the dir command at a command prompt if you're interested).

It's worth noting that applications running up to the 2.0 CLR will not even be able to see assemblies in the new GAC.

Comment: Thanks for answering! It covered all my questions.

Answer (score 19):

Try:

```
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\
```

Comment: Do you know if there is an extension to windows explorer to see the details of the assemblies, like public key token, just as the %windir%\assembly does?

Comment: @Carlos Loth - Sorry, I don't.

Comment: Apparently the GAC viewer shell extension (shfusion.dll) has been discontinued for .NET 4.0, and no longer ships with the framework.

On a machine with 3.5 and 4.0, I copied the Desktop.ini file from %windir%\assembly to %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly (after doing "attrib Desktop.ini -h -r -s" from a command prompt), but this still did not work, even in a new instance of Windows Explorer.

Comment: How can I install .NET 4.0 assembly in the GAC ? gacutil fails for me... Failure adding assembly to the cache

Answer (score 0):

Due to Common Language Runtime (CLR) changes, the contents of the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) is split between two directories:

- `%WINDIR%\assembly\`
- `%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\`

If you run the command `gacutil -l` from the directory of your project's `.csproj` file, you will get a printout of the contents of the GAC (the contents of both directories).