# How can I list all registered assemblies in GAC?

Tags: .net, assemblies, gac

How can I list all the assemblies that are in the GAC? Do I need a tool that makes it easy to view them?

Comment: See the link [http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/demystifygac.aspx](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/demystifygac.aspx)

Comment: You accidentally a verb.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

You can use gacutil provided with Visual Studio for that. Simply open the Developer Command Prompt (available in Start Menu>App>Visual Studio) and run the following command:

```
gacutil -l >yourassemblies.txt
```

Gacutil is also available as a separate download if you don't have/want Visual Studio.

Comment: If (like me) your not sure where the gacutil is, you can access it from the visual studio command prompt

Comment: Or see here for file path to the gacutil command (comes with Visual Studio):
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397479/where-is-gacutil-exe

Answer (score 13):

If you need the output in text-form, you can use [`gacutil /l`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c%28v=VS.100%29.aspx).

If you need to get that list from inside, say, an installer or other tool of your own, you might want to look into the [APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/unmanaged-api/fusion/) to query the GAC.

Also, since originally asked, there are some projects using this API already.
Just search the internet for "fusion gac .net". For example [this one](https://github.com/voyce/gachelper).

Answer (score 12):

You can actually navigate to the GAC via explorer or the command line and view the contents of the folder.  It's location is **C:\Windows\assembly**.

When viewing via explorer the actual files are hidden and abstracted away, if you need to copy or extract specific versions of the dlls the command line is the way to go.

You can also turn off the namespace extension [as explained here](http://geekswithblogs.net/pavelka/archive/2006/05/05/WindowsExplorerAndTheGlobalAssemblyCache.aspx) - which will make explorer act as usual in the GAC.

Comment: .NET 4.0 [has a separate GAC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why), so make sure you're [looking at the right path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823068/where-is-the-net-framework-global-assembly-cache).