# Is there any way to find the assemblies by name pattern rather than exact name from GAC?

Tags: .net, windows

I use gacutil to add/remove assemblies to GAC, I can find the assemblies installed in gac by providing exact name, but is there any way to find assemblies by name pattern/partial match?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want this? Anyway you can [list them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469405/how-can-i-list-all-registered-assemblies-in-gac), pipe that list into a text file and run some regular expressions on the list using your favorite text editor or from code.

Then you can remove the assemblies you want to.

Comment: I need to verify if some assemblies are installed or not. Listing all assemblies doesn't do any good as it gives a list of ~3K assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

There is no off the shelf option. You can write custom application to iterate GAC assemblies and cater filter logic.

Or

Use application like A GAC Manager Utility and API

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/430568/A-GAC-Manager-Utility-and-API