# GacUtil + .net framework 4.0

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, gacutil

I added an assembly to the GAC using the Visual Studio 2010 command prompt.

```
gacutil /i xxx
```

It shows a message:

> Assembly successfully added to the cache.

But it's not visible in `C:\WINDOWS\assembly` and I read that the .NET Framework GAC has been moved to `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly` for v4.0 assemblies. I searched for my assembly there as well but I cannot find it. So where do I find the installed assembly for the .NET Framework v4.0?

Comment: `I searched` is too vague.  Another change is the shell extension handler that makes the GAC look like a single directory.  It is not there anymore.

Comment: But it's not coming in Add Reference on VisualStudio

Comment: That's normal, that dialog never shows assemblies in the GAC.  It only shows reference assemblies.  Use the Browse tab instead.  *Never* put your assemblies in the GAC on your dev machine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for .Net Framework 4 GAC is in this location %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly

See here [Where is the .NET Framework Global Assembly Cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823068/where-is-the-net-framework-global-assembly-cache)