# MSTest assemblies list

Tags: list, assemblies, teamcity, mstest

Hello I am trying to run driven tests in **teamcity 6.5**
since I am not familiar with .net terms and I don't know what are the *assemblies list* or how to create them can you please help me! thank you

Comment: do some research before asking for advice. People here are happy to help when you get stuck with a particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the usual MSTest setup, when you build an MSTest project, you get a dll. A dll is an assembly (a .exe also is an assembly, and there are other, more exotic assembly types). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972732/what-is-net-assembly)'s an SO question on that subject.

So what TeamCity wants in that list are the paths to the MSTest dlls it will feed to the test runner.