# In C#, How Can I Use Public Class Members(Methods Or Variables) From Different Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-assembly, access-specifier, class-members

I am working on C# encapsulation from Tutorialspoint.com. And I read this

```
What is the difference between Public, Private, Protected, and Nothing?1
```

question from Stackoverflow. I read answer and i understood access specifiers in teoric. Now I want to make console application with this subject in visual studio.

> ***public***
>
> > *The type or member can be accessed by any other code in the same assembly or another assembly that references it.*
>
> ***private***
>
> > *The type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class or struct.*
>
> ***protected***
>
> > *The type or member can only be accessed by code in the same class or struct, or in a derived class.*
>
> ***internal***
>
> > *The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, but not from another assembly.*
>
> ***protected internal***
>
> > *The type or member can be accessed by any code in the same assembly, or by any derived class in another assembly.*

Variables or methods with public access specifier are accessed from same assembly and different assembly. But this station is different in internal description. Internal types variables and methods can accessed only same assembly but not different assembly in c#. I want to test this station in C#.So that i create two project and call method or variables between each other.

[image: My Project Hierarchy]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TutorialsPoint.Encapsulation
{
   public class PublicEncapsulation
    {
        //member variables
        public double length;
        public double width;


        public double GetArea()
        {
            return length * width;
        }

        public void Display()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Length: {0}", length);
            Console.WriteLine("Width: {0}", width);
            Console.WriteLine("Area: {0}", GetArea());
        }

    }
}
```

Above code is my 'PublicEncapsulation.cs' and i should call its members from other assembly.My other assembly project's class is Program.cs. I want to connect PublicEncapsulation.cs's members from Program.cs(other assembly). How can i do this calling operation from other assemblies in c#.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Collections;

namespace CallOtherAssemblyVariablesOrMethods
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            /*Call PublicEncapsulation.cs's members in there.*/
        }
    }
}
```

Above class is Program.cs. I want to call other asssembly PublicEncapsulation.cs's members in here.

Comment: Hmmm... I though it should be duplicate of [What is .Net Assembly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972732/what-is-net-assembly) based on title, but your post clearly shows that you know how to create multiple assemblies... Possibly you need to update title (and maybe show code instead of image).

Comment: "i should call its members from other assembly" Well then don't mark them as internal. I'm having a very difficult time trying to understand what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 days ago i have an simple problems. I solved my my problems with Stackoverflow. I wanted to see difference between internal and public access specifier. And then i created two project to see difference of them. If i could call public methods  and couldn't call internal methods from other assembly and then theoretical knowledge is supported with C# console application. I wanted to do this. But i can't see other project's public members. And then i found solution in this                    [How to use a Class from one C# project with another C# project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3554658/how-to-use-a-class-from-one-c-sharp-project-with-another-c-sharp-project][1])  tutorial. I should have added reference in project with right click.

> ***SOLUTION STEPS***
>
> **1.** *In the 'Solution Explorer' tree, expand the
>       'CallOtherAssemblyVariablesOrMethods' project and then right-click
>       the project and select 'Add Reference' from the menu.*
>
> **2.** *On the 'AddReference' dialog, select the 'Projects' tab and select your
>       'TutorialsPoint ' project.*
>
> **3.** *If you are using namespaces then you will need to import the namespaces     for your 'CallOtherAssemblyVariablesOrMethods' types by adding 'using'*   statements to your files in 'TutorialsPoint'.

Many thanks to everyone...

Answer (score 3):

I guess in your Program.cs you have something like this:

```
var typeFromOtherAssembly = new InternalEncapsulation();

// Here you expect a compiler error:
var area = typeFromOtherAssembly.GetArea();

// This should return a string.
var details = typeFromOtherAssembly.Display();
```

You think the `new` and `Display()` would work, and that the (internal) `GetArea()` call would show a compiler error:

> 'InternalEncapsulation' does not contain a definition for 'GetArea' and no extension method 'GetArea' accepting a first argument of type 'InternalEncapsulation' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

But you didn't specify an access modifier for the `InternalEncapsulation` class, so it's [internal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx):

> Internal is the default if no access modifier is specified.

So at `new InternalEncapsulation` you get another compiler error:

> `InternalEncapsulation` is inaccessible due to its protection level

So you need to make it public:

```
public class InternalEncapsulation
```

Comment: An assembly is a "unit of deployment" for .NET, almost always a .exe or .dll.
In C# terms, it's basically a single C# project. Source: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/088ce8ed-ef9b-4dea-88b3-ca016885e26d/what-is-an-assembly-in-terms-of-c?forum=csharplanguage

Comment: @fsacer I'm not sure that should be a comment to my answer. OP's question is not "what is an assembly".

Comment: He asked if those projects were diffrent assemblies so I guess this answers it.

Comment: @CodeCaster, Can you access PublicEncapsulation.cs's members from Program.cs.I will share my PublicEncapsulation.cs.

Comment: @MertÖzoğul note that your "PublicEncapsualtion" is internal class as show in the question... I'd strongly recommend to either rename it to match default access modifier or specify non-default modifier explicitly (same as covered in this answer for other class).