# LoadLibrary() function from kernel32.dll couldn't load 64-bit assembly files

Tags: c#, kernel32

I am using LoadLibrary function from kernel32.dll to load some 64-bit assembly files with full file path in C#. But it returns null pointer. And also it returns 0 for getLastError() function. Below is the function definition code in C#.

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll"), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
static extern uint LoadLibraryEx(string fileName, uint notUsedMustBeZero, uint flags);
```

Below is the code that I tried to load the 64-bit assembly.

```
var hLib = LoadLibraryEx(filePath, 0, DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES | LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL);
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Why do you want to LoadLibrary an _assembly_, by which I assume you mean a .NET assembly? And what bitness is your application compiled with? Also, use `SetLastError=true` to be able to call `GetLastError()`.

Comment: Assembly is not only mean .Net assembly. It means all managed and unmanaged assembly files.
I didn't set  SetLastError=true. I will try with that also.

Comment: I don't know the bitness of the application that compiled with.

Comment: No, in the context of DLLs, "assembly" means a [".NET Assembly"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2972732/what-are-net-assemblies). An [unmanaged PE DLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic-link_library) is not called an "assembly".