# Where does VS 2010 Tools' gacutil.exe install assemblies?

Tags: .net, windows, assemblies, gac, gacutil

I used the Visual Studio 2010 Command Prompt's gacutil.exe to install an assembly.  I expected the assembly to be added to `C:\WINDOWS\assemblies`, but it was instead added to `C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL` and is not showing up in `C:\WINDOWS\assemblies`.  Is this a problem and should I be concerned that it's not showing up there?

Comment: What OS are you using -- I don't even have a `C:\WINDOWS\assemblies` on this Vista install

Comment: We went through this in your previous question.  No, it is not a problem.

Comment: @Hans sorry...i had asked this question before realizing you had answered my other question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GAC location was changed in .Net 4. Check [.NET 4.0 has a new GAC, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why) for details.