# Gacutil not installed by default in VisualStudio

Tags: visual-studio, .net-assembly, gacutil

I am unable to add an assembly into GAC. Please assist in getting it work. I ran following command in VisualStudio13 CMD

```
gacutil /i “<C:\Program Files\ibm\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER>\bin\netf40_32\IBM.Data.DB2.Entity.dll”
```

Error Message:
**Command "gacutil" is not valid**.

Also, i checked there is also no gacutil.exe file on path

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0
>   Tools

[image: C:\Program Files (x86)>dir gacutil.exe /s Command gives me following description]

But when i access the path there is no gacutil file as shown:
[image: Folder view No gacutil present]

Comment: It's weird that it's missing. You could try installing the SDK as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7968775/119477) suggests

Comment: I installed Windows SDK @Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0  There is still no GACUTIL.exe in it.  It must be included in VS13 as well. I went through your suggested answer link earlier but no good :(

Comment: I know it sounds obvious but did you try doing something like `C:\Program Files (x86)>dir gacutil.exe /s` I found no less than 12 versions of it

Comment: It finds gacutil.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools  AND   
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64.  But no such files visible.  Also, there are visible gacutil named files in SDK path like  
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin however in .\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64 path i cant find one.

Comment: I'm confused. You say that dir finds it but then you say no such files are visible. Can you explain what you mean by not visible?

Comment: Hope, I am able to make things a lil clear with Post edited.

Comment: Don't trust windows explorer. Trust command. Try adding one of the gacutil locations to your path or use the whole path and it should work. e.g. `" C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" /i "C:\Program Files\ibm\IBM DATA SERVER DRIVER>\bin\netf40_32\IBM.Data.DB2.Entity.dll"`

Comment: Nailed it. Using cmd Full path names are working !!!! :) :) Thanks a bunch Sir Frix (y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was Windows Explorer path(**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe**) had no "gacutil.exe". Accessing the same path through **cmd** listed down "gacutil.exe" as present.

Thus, instead of just giving command gacutil-i  to add an assembly in cache, i gave full path

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0Tools\gacutil.exe -i

**Don't trust windows explorer. Trust command** credits@ Sir Conrad Frix-Comments

Comment: That is not the issue, you are not supposed to have a "NETFX 4.0 Tools" subdirectory at all.  Not in SDK v7.0a, that directory only got added in later SDK versions.  How sn.exe ended up there is very hard to guess, it doesn't belong there at all, something went wrong on your machine a while ago.  Just in case, *never* fix a build problem by copying files.  You are supposed to use the 8.1A version of gacutil, the SDK version married to VS2013.  Looks like you simply forgot to use the Visual Studio Command Prompt (aka vcvarsall.bat).

Comment: Passant@ Thanks for looking into the problem. The VS13 Command Prompt was giving :            >gacutil -i
Command "gacutil" is not valid.

Answer (score 0):

You can either drag-drop the .dll into c:\windows\assembly folder or check C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.6 Tools\x64 for gacutil as its part of .net framework, not your IDE. Hope it helps!

Comment: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\x64 . I double checked this path again. No good.