# Can't find an assembly in the GAC which application is using

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gac

I need to update an assembly that my application is using.

It is a website application referencing the assembly in the GAC via this line in the web.config

```
<add assembly="dotnetCHARTING, Version=4.3.2721.21869, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=AF2CD47DB69D93BD" />
```

However I am confused, I cannot find the assembly in C:\Windows\assembly or C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Assembly

I even tried this tool, no dice.
http://gacbrowser.blogspot.co.uk/2008/03/gac-browser-introduction.html

I have tried looking via the public key and assembly name.

Any ideas?

(Edited - converted web.config line to code sample)

Comment: Please confirm that the assembly is in the GAC. Check what application **is** using by attaching debugger and checking list of loaded modules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the .NET [Fusion Logger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)? It should tell you the exact path that the assembly was loaded from.

Comment: Or just look in the bin folder.  If it's not in the GAC it's in one of the other locations searched for assemblies.

Answer (score 1):

What version of .Net are you using?  In .Net4, the location of the GAC changed.  See this question for more details:  [.NET 4.0 has a new GAC, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why)

Answer (score 0):

Try Create dump or mini dump using process explorer.
It will show all the dll's your application is using.