# GACUtil: Installing Assembly

Tags: gac

I added two assemblies using GACUtil. Both were added successfully however one shows up under C:\Windows\Assembly and the other under C:\Windows\Microsoft\Assembly\GAC_MSIL".

Why would it happen this way when i had used the same command for both assemblies?

Thanks

Manny

Comment: How is this a SharePoint question?

Comment: Technically it is more of a .NET question. But i am referencing the assemblies inside Sharepoint (v4.master), I figured Ill post it here.

Comment: You should probably clarify that then as DLLs are never deployed via GACUtil in SharePoint.  They are deployed as part of a solution which takes care of issues like this automatically

Answer (score 1):

> In .NET Framework 4.0, the GAC went through a few changes. The GAC was
>   split into two, one for each CLR.
>
> The CLR version used for both .NET Framework 2.0 and .NET Framework
>   3.5 is CLR 2.0. There was no need in the previous two framework releases to split GAC. The problem of breaking older applications in
>   Net Framework 4.0.
>
> To avoid issues between CLR 2.0 and CLR 4.0 , the GAC is now split
>   into private GAC’s for each runtime.The main change is that CLR v2.0
>   applications now cannot see CLR v4.0 assemblies in the GAC.

[.NET 4.0 has a new GAC, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why)

hope this answers it for you :)