# why "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32..." instead of "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32"

Tags: c#, dll, wix, gac, .net-assembly

`<Component Guid="7F7333F5-F9ED-4712-8D1B-58AAC71790CB" Id="MyComponent">
     <File Name="MyDll.dll" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" 
          Id="MyDLL_GAC" Assembly=".net" Source="$(var.COMTRACERDIR)\MyDll.dll">
     </File>
</Component>`

When I use this to make a *.msi with wix, I just found the dll will be install in the path "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32..." instead of "C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_32".

Answer (score 5):

Because one is the 4.0 CLR's GAC, the other is the 2.0 GAC - but the issue is complicated further still. More information is available here: [.NET 4.0 has a new GAC, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why)