# Enumerate remote GAC Assembly

Tags: c#, gac

I would like to list all assembly entries (GAC) starting with "IN" or "IP" on a domain, I found several ways to do it locally but not remotely.

I would like to display all info available (size, version, date, ...) and I son't really know how to handle it.

Comment: Did you consider the tool PsExec from SysInternals ?

Answer (score 1):

GACed assemblies are stored in the "%windir%\Microsoft.Net\assembly" directory on each machine (but can be a bit more complicated then that in .Net 4.0. See [.NET 4.0 has a new GAC, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why) for more information). That directory contains the GAC-32. GAC_64 and GAC_MSIL for 32-bit, 64-bit and processor independent assemblies and each of those folders contains a folder for each assembly. You could iterate the folders in that directory on each computer, such as using [WMI File and Folder access](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394594%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and find the assemblies you are looking for.

Comment: In fact I am searching for specific Dlls installed not presents in Microsoft.net folder, the goal is to list it, thanks for your help.