# Where is GAC (Global Assembly Cache) located? How it is Useful?

Tags: c#, .net

I read more about GAC but i am not clear till now.

Few things what i gathered is, GAC has same assembly with different versions. But i cannot able to find how to create two assembly with different versions and keeping in same folder.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is located in %windir%\assembly (for example, C:\WINDOWS\assembly) and it is a shared repository of libraries.

Comment: Not strictly true... .NET 4.0 and above uses new repository so you can now have two. More here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why

Comment: You're right. My answer was something general, just as the question.