# GAC assembly found but not in C:\Windows\assembly\

Tags: .net-4.0, x86, .net-assembly, odp.net, gac

Notice how the 4.0 version of the ODP.NET Oracle Provider (Oracle.DataAccess.dll) shows up in the GAC when I search for it using the gacutil.exe utility.  But it doesn't exist in the C:\windows\assembly\ folder.  Why would that be?  How can I find and extract that dll from the GAC?  Only the 2.x assemblies are in the folder.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools>gacuti
l /l Oracle.DataAccess
Microsoft (R) .NET Global Assembly Cache Utility.  Version 4.0.30319.33440
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

The Global Assembly Cache contains the following assemblies:
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f4
29c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=2.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f4
29c47342, processorArchitecture=x86
  Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f4
29c47342, processorArchitecture=x86

Number of items = 3

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\bin\NETFX 4.5.1 Tools>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the dll was in a different folder.

C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32\Oracle.DataAccess\v4.0_4.112.3.0__89b483f429c47342\oracle.dataaccess.dll

Comment: .net 4.0 and above uses a new GAC location:  
http://stackoverflow.com/a/2660366/852208