# "Information" property on Streams property of Powershell instance not available compiletime

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

So.. very odd problem.

Using VS2015 and .net 4.52

I developed this C# powershell code, it is running a script and catches the output. like this:

```
        using (PowerShell powerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create())
        {
            powerShellInstance.AddScript(scriptContents);

            Collection<PSObject> PSOutput = powerShellInstance.Invoke(); 

            if (powerShellInstance.Streams.Information.Count > 0)
            {

                    foreach (var item in powerShellInstance.Streams.Information)
                    {
                        //do something with info
                    }


                }

            }
        }
```

Compiles and runs (on a Windows 10 pro machine), no problems.

Until I got a new machine (surface pro 4, so also windows 10 pro) and tried to compile the code, I get this error:

> 'PSDataStreams' does not contain a definition for 'Information' and no extension method 'Information' accepting a first argument of type 'PSDataStreams' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

This is all TFS based, so I'm sure it is the same code.

If I goto definition on the two machines the problem becomes obvious:

[image]

So, I commented out the not compiling code and ran it, to see what was happening runtime:

[image]

So the property IS there.. Anybody got a good explanation for this?

BTW: the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.psdatastreams_properties(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation does not mention an Information property..

Comment: Did you have Powershell 5 Preview installed on the old system, but not the new one? Or perhaps different versions of it between the two?

Comment: No, this a clean win 10 machine, with only studio installed

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might be referencing the wrong version of the `System.Management.Automation.dll` assembly on the Surface Pro.

On my Windows 10 Pro installation (upgraded from Windows 8.1), I have two versions, [one in each GAC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why):

[image: 2 ps versions]

The one selected in the picture is the "old" one, lives in the old GAC (`C:\windows\assembly`) and identifies itself with the File Version 6.1.7600.16385.

The other one (which contains the correct version of `PSDataStreams` and exposes the `Information` stream) lives in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly` and has File Version 10.0.10240.16384 as of writing.

Comment: Huh.. I'm referencing C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\WindowsPowerShell\3.0\System.Management.Automation.dll
Are there three?

Comment: But as you can see in the first screenshot I'm referencing exactly the same file.. that is.. the same location..

Comment: Weird stuff..
There are indeed three, the two you mention and the one I used. They are all different. File sizes ~1mb, ~3mb and ~ 6mb.

Comment: Btw.. since when are there 2 GAC's?

Comment: The assembly version of all are the same: 3.0.0.0. but the file version is different.. I guess that is the source of the problem

Comment: @Flores 2 GAC's since release of CLR version 4.0. The one from the PowerShell 3.0 SDK (the one in Referenced Assemblies) won't work, the Information stream is introduced in PowerShell 5.0