# Where "Write-Host" output goes in Powershell System.Management.Automation Reference assemblies 4.0

Tags: c#, pipeline, powershell-4.0, runspace

I am using System.Management.Automation with reference assemblies 4.0 with C#

I need to see the output of Write-Host. Documentation says that Write-Host will be outputted in the output stream. What is the output stream for getting Write-Host output in C# while using reference assemblies of powershell 4.0.

I know Information pipeline was being later added in Powershell version 5.0 and Write-Host and Write-Information always pipe the output to Information Pipeline.

But I need to see the output of Write-Host while with reference assemblies for powershell 4.0. With the following code, I am not able to see the output of Write-Host anywhere. Nor at output and not in the output collections.

Currently I have subscribed to following streams.

```
using (var powerShell = PowerShell.Create(iss))
{           
    var psScript = "Write-Host test input";
    powerShell.AddScript(psScript);

    powerShell.Streams.Debug.DataAdding += OnDebugDataAdding; 
    powerShell.Streams.Error.DataAdding += OnErrorAdding;
    powerShell.Streams.Warning.DataAdding += OnWarningAdding;
    powerShell.Streams.Verbose.DataAdding += OnVerboseAdding;

    var outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
    outputCollection.DataAdding += OnOutputDataAdding; // all spitted outputs getting into outputCollection

    powerShell.Invoke(null, outputCollection);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I found an answer to effectively this same question at [How can I execute scripts in a code created powershell shell that has Write-Host commands in it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24290813/how-can-i-execute-scripts-in-a-code-created-powershell-shell-that-has-write-host)

Before your AddScript call, add these two statements:

```
powerShell.AddScript("function Write-Host($out) {Write-Output $out}").Invoke();
powerShell.Commands.Clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using the Pipeline class, you can use the `Command.MergeMyResults` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.runspaces.command.mergemyresults?view=powershellsdk-7.0.0). For example, to redirect all type of streams to pipeline output:

```
private string RunScript(string scriptText) {

    Runspace runspace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace();

    runspace.Open();

    Pipeline pipeline = runspace.CreatePipeline();
    pipeline.Commands.AddScript("Write-Host Test");
    pipeline.Commands[pipeline.Commands.Count-1]
       .MergeMyResults(PipelineResultTypes.All, PipelineResultTypes.Output)
    
    Collection < PSObject > results = pipeline.Invoke();

    runspace.Close();

    foreach(PSObject obj in results) {
        Console.WriteLine(obj.ToString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is specifically for System.Management.Automation **version 4.0**; my solution was to [upgrade to Version 5.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34383106/788168).

Then you can [use the `Information` stream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59988533/788168), as the question-asker noted:

```cs
// ...

// Write-Host goes to this stream.
// Only available if you use a modern version of PowerShellStandard.Library (>=5.1.0)
instance.Streams.Information.DataAdded += (sender, e) =>
{
  Console.WriteLine($"Info: {info}");
};
```

I figured it was worth noting here, since I encountered this question and I was able to upgrade my PowerShell DLLs :).