# Is there an easier way to view/search what is in the GAC?

Tags: c#, gac

I know that Microsoft states to run

```
gacutil -l
```

from the VS command prompt to get a list.

However I am dealing with this.
[image]

So when I run the list the display contents are all over the window and I have a total of 1649 items in the gac.  
In this case I do now know what Oracal dll I need to remove.  So is there an easier way to view/search what is in the GAC?

Comment: Are you aware of using windows explorer and browsing to c:\windows\assembly?  Whether you consider that easier or not...

Comment: I did not.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use Windows Explorer to browse the GAC.  Open it up and navigate to `%systemroot%\assembly`:

[image]

You can see various details of each assembly, and pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> will prompt you if you want to uninstall the assembly.

Answer (score 12):

Searching in c:\windows\assembly is not going to help as from .net 4.0 on wards there is a different location (%windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly) for GAC.

See here [.NET 4.0 has a new GAC, why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660355/net-4-0-has-a-new-gac-why)

`gacutil` is the way to go as it searches in both the locations i.e. %systemroot%\assembly and %windir%\Microsoft.NET\assembly\

For your issue you can try

`gacutil -l Oracle.DataAccess` (Oracle.DataAccess.dll is what I remember gets installed for Oracle Data Provider for .NET)

However above command doesn't support wild card so the assembly name should exactly match.

A hack would be to pipe the result to find command and then apply filters

`gacutil.exe -l | find /I "oracle"` (make sure VS command prompt is opened in admin mode)

Comment: I'm not great with PowerShell, but getting the full GAC list and filtering within the same query sounds like something it would be good at.

Comment: Good point. In fact we can pipe result to MS-Dos find command and apply filter there, edited my answer.